# ¿Como paso una imagen desde mi vista a un controlador? MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvc, imagen, post

Hola tengo el siguiente problema, necesito obtener una imagen de un input y pasarlo al controlador; el codigo que utilizo es el siguiente:
HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 offset-sm-1">
        <input name="Portada" type="file" id="filePicker" />
    </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="button" onclick="Modificar()">Guardar cambios</button>
```

JS:

```
function Modificar() {
      var Portada = $('#filePicker').prop("files")[0];
        var url = "@Url.Action("Modificar", "Dispositivos")";
        var data = { Portada: Portada };
        $.post(url, data).done(function (data) {
            if (data) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Controlador:

```
 public ActionResult Modificar(HttpPostedFileBase Portada)
    {--- codigoControlador}
```

Con éste código da un error en js y no llega al controlador, si el input queda null si entra en el controlador. Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para enviar un fichero al controlador lo que tendrías que hacer en el lado del cliente es esto:

```
function Modificar() {
 var fichero = document.getElementById("filePicker").files[0];
 var datosFormulario = new FormData();
 datosFormulario.append("imagen", fichero);
 datosFormulario.append("Id", 2);
 $.ajax({
    url: 'http://ejemplo.com/accionControlador/',
    data: datosFormulario,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
      alert(data);
 }
```

});
    }

En el controlador

```
public ActionResult Modificar(int Id){
    if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
        }
}
```

}

La ventaja que tienes al usar FormData es que puedes enviar todos los ficheros que quieras y también los datos que necesites. En el ejemplo puedes ver que he añadido el valor de Id.

Saludos.

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias por la ayuda